# Why is my robotic arm laying down in Gazebo after configure it with MoveIt Setup Assistant?

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to ROS and all the tools surrounding ROS. Currently, I am trying to setup a franka emika (panda) robot arm using moveit setup assistant. After that, I just wanna launch the robot in the Gazebo simulation using the command

> roslaunch package_name gazebo.launch

However, as you can see below, the robot collapse when spawned.

[image: image description]

Here are some of the messages capture in the terminal (shown in the picture below):

[image: image description]

I have gone through past questions on similar problems online, but it seems like the files generated from the setup assistant is a little different, hence I wasn't able to locate what are the mistakes.

Below also I will attach the code for the robot urdf:

**panda_arm.urdf.xacro:**

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="panda">

  <xacro:arg name="arm_id" default="panda" /> <!-- Name of this panda -->
  <xacro:arg name="hand"   default="true" /> <!-- Should a franka_gripper be mounted at the flange?" -->
  <xacro:arg name="gazebo" default="true" /> <!-- Is the robot being simulated in gazebo?" -->

  <xacro:property name="arm_id" value="$(arg arm_id)" />

  <xacro:unless value="$(arg gazebo)">
    <!-- Create a URDF for a real hardware -->
    <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/panda_arm.xacro" />
    <xacro:panda_arm arm_id="${arm_id}" safety_distance="0.03"/>

    <xacro:if value="$(arg hand)">
      <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/hand.xacro"/>
      <xacro:hand ns="${arm_id}" rpy="0 0 ${-pi/4}" connected_to="${arm_id}_link8" safety_distance="0.03"/>
    </xacro:if>
  </xacro:unless>

  <xacro:if value="$(arg gazebo)">

    <xacro:arg name="xyz" default="0 0 0" />
    <xacro:arg name="rpy" default="0 0 0" />

    <!-- Create a simulatable URDF -->
    <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/utils.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/panda_gazebo.xacro" />

    <xacro:panda_arm arm_id="${arm_id}" />

    <xacro:if value="$(arg hand)">
      <xacro:hand ns="${arm_id}" rpy="0 0 ${-pi/4}" connected_to="${arm_id}_link8" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_finger_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_finger_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    </xacro:if>

    <!-- Gazebo requires a joint to a link called "world" for statically mounted robots -->
    <link name="world" />
    <joint name="world_joint" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="$(arg xyz)" rpy="$(arg rpy)" />
      <parent link="world" />
      <child  link="${arm_id}_link0" />
    </joint>


    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint3" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint4" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint5" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint6" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint7" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />

    <xacro:transmission-franka-state arm_id="${arm_id}" />
    <xacro:transmission-franka-model arm_id="${arm_id}"
       root="${arm_id}_joint1"
       tip="${arm_id}_joint8"
     />

    <gazebo>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
        <robotNamespace>${arm_id}</robotNamespace>
        <controlPeriod>0.001</controlPeriod>
        <robotSimType>franka_gazebo/FrankaHWSim</robotSimType>
      </plugin>
      <self_collide>true</self_collide>
    </gazebo>
  </xacro:if>

</robot>
```

Here's the launch file **launch/gazebo.launch**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="gazebo_gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="initial_joint_positions" doc="Initial joint configuration of the robot"
       default=" -J panda_joint1 0 -J panda_joint2 0 -J panda_joint3 0 -J panda_joint4 -1.7149 -J panda_joint5 0 -J panda_joint6 1.4613 -J panda_joint7 0"/>

  <!-- startup simulated world -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gazebo_gui)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- send robot urdf to param server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="xacro  '$(find franka_description)/robots/panda_arm.urdf.xacro'" />

  <!-- unpause only after loading robot model -->
  <arg name="unpause" value="$(eval '' if arg('paused') else '-unpause')" />
  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo at the origin, change x,y,z arguments to spawn in a different position -->
  <arg name="world_pose" value="-x 0 -y 0 -z 0" />
  <node name="spawn_gazebo_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -model robot $(arg unpause) $(arg world_pose) $(arg initial_joint_positions)"
    respawn="false" output="screen" />

  <!-- Load joint controller parameters for Gazebo -->
  <rosparam file="$(find panda_config)/config/gazebo_controllers.yaml" />
  <!-- Spawn Gazebo ROS controllers -->
  <node name="gazebo_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="joint_state_controller" />
  <!-- Load ROS controllers -->
  <include file="$(dirname)/ros_controllers.launch"/>

</launch>
```

I am not sure what other files I should provide in here. Let me know if you need me to show you more part of the code. Thanks for helping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395014/why-is-my-robotic-arm-laying-down-in-gazebo-after-configure-it-with-moveit-setup-assistant?/) by [HynRidge](https://answers.ros.org/users/94307/hynridge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2022-01-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-25**:
Have you followed the [tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/gazebo_simulation/gazebo_simulation.html)? There are a few steps required to make the arm work in Gazebo.

**Comment by [HynRidge](https://answers.ros.org/users/94307/hynridge/) on 2022-01-25**:
@osilva Regarding this matter, I found out that the files that are currently used in the tutorial are different from the updated franka package, hence wasn't able to follow the tutorial properly. Perhaps do you know any solution about this?

**Comment by [HynRidge](https://answers.ros.org/users/94307/hynridge/) on 2022-01-25**:
@osilva EDIT: I have followed the tutorial and manage to launch the gazebo and spawned a non-collapsed robot arm now. However, after terminating and relaunch the gazebo a few time, the robot is not spawned anymore.

**There's are the error messages provided in the terminal:**

```
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 35304, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -u -e ode worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/heinrich/.ros/log/1e14ad80-7e51-11ec-84af-99a9762c0757/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/heinrich/.ros/log/1e14ad80-7e51-11ec-84af-99a9762c0757/gazebo-2*.log
```

EDIT: I've checked the logfile, but found nothing crucial/ fixable

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-26**:
Since the original issue is resolved on being able to use Gazebo. I suggest you start a new question for the new issue. That way more people can help you

**Comment by [HynRidge](https://answers.ros.org/users/94307/hynridge/) on 2022-01-27**:
Understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve this issue by following the tutorial from the attached websites:
https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/gazebo_simulation/gazebo_simulation.html

---

Originally posted by [HynRidge](https://answers.ros.org/users/94307/hynridge/) with karma: 56 on 2022-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1